# Can Only Texture Paint Part of My Object

Tags: texture-painting

New to Blender (probably obvious by the question). I've got a low poly rock asset with a normal map. I'm now trying to paint a rock texture. I can paint part of the rock but not others. That's part of the issue. Here's another part. I can eventually paint the texture after sitting around on my thumbs for a bit. I leave Blender alone for a bit. Come back. Try again - not having closed it or touched it. Magically I can paint it. Why? I have a super beefy computer so no issues with processing power. I'm using the Draw Brush, I've got a rock material, a rock texture image, and a new brush. I'm using the Stencil for the Brush Mapping but I also get same results with Tiled.

Things I've checked:

- The faces are all facing the right way - every face is blue in Face Orientation overlay.
- I also checked the normals. All facing the right way (little blue lines coming out the center of every face).
- I tried unchecking Occluded in the Options drop-down.
- I deleted the original brush and texture and made new ones. No difference.
- Confirmed Cavity Mask is off.

[image]

[image]

Also going to ask another question, which is why is their texture paint on the uv editor outside the UVs (as seen in pic 2)? Shouldn't it stay within the bounds of the UVs?

Comment: It looks to me like you have a separate part of the mesh that is not what you intend to be painting - see that square around the boundary? That is a single face that is unwrapped or a stack of them, as well as the islands there that are obviously unwrapped intentionally. Check your model that there isn't something oddly going on, maybe turn on UV Sync Selection in Edit mode to see what that big square is or hwo it relates to the texture map and the model.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/